# jquery - Changing ID reference to Numeric value

Tags: jquery, html

I'm using HTML 5 as well as jquery v1.8.2 to trigger an event to pop out an item when you reach the end of an article page. Though it works well, I'm trying to see if I can replace the trigger-able id (#last) event with a numeric call (pixel/percentage).

This code is intended to be used on an article page. When you get towards end of the article, a modal will pop. Currently, too get the modal to pop, it's finding the height of the id (#last) and popping based on the height of the element with the id #last.
All I'm trying to do is: instead of using an id to trigger the event, use a numeric value. For instance, when the page has scrolled 66% from the top, firing the pop out modal event.

Here's the code:

```
$(function() {
$(window).scroll(function(){
var distanceTop = $('#last').offset().top - $(window).height();
if  ($(window).scrollTop() > distanceTop)
$('#toolbar-btm-button').fadeIn('slow').animate({bottom: '0'},"slow");
else 
$('#toolbar-btm-button').animate({bottom: '-44px'},"fast");    
});
});
```

I tried replacing #last with a pixel and percentage value, but it didn't seem to work correctly. This is what I tried and it didn't work:

```
$(function() {
$(window).scroll(function(){
var distanceTop = $('66%').offset().top - $(window).height();
if  ($(window).scrollTop() > distanceTop)
$('#toolbar-btm-button').fadeIn('slow').animate({bottom: '0'},"slow");
else 
$('#toolbar-btm-button').animate({bottom: '-44px'},"fast");    
});
});
```

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
$(function() {
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var distanceTop = $('body').height() - $(window).height();
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > (distanceTop * 0.6)) {
            $('#toolbar-btm-button').fadeIn('slow').animate({
                bottom: '0'
            }, "slow");
        } else {
            $('#toolbar-btm-button').animate({
                bottom: '-44px'
            }, "fast");
        }
    });
});​
```